# Removing Unity on Desktop Ubuntu 15.04 and using Gnome 3

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.04

I'm running into an issue when trying to convert from using Unity to just Gnome 3.

I keep ending up with the GUI looking as such, with remnants of Unity's Close, Minimize, and Maximize buttons.

[image: Nautilus after Unity removal]

I've tried several variations between removing and adding the following packages, since I read that there are packages that overlap between Unity and Gnome 3. Without knowing exactly which packages are needed, I've just tried removing as little to as much as I can, then "patching" back what's needed if it's been removed.

`gnome-desktop-environment
gnome-shell
gnome-core
ubuntu-desktop
unity`

But no matter how much I `apt-get autoremove`, the GUI never turns out right. Removing `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity` has gotten me the closest, but the Close button becomes this thin, and elongated button.

There has to be something else that I'm missing. Where it isn't as simple as just `apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment` and choosing `Gnome` on the login screen. But it should be that simple.

Comment: "Where it isn't as simple" It is as simple as that. Can you please describe how did you install Gnome Shell?

Comment: @xangua `apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`, and then switching to different themes; and turning off maximize and minimize buttons in TweakUI.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have no words. The time that I decided to post this as a question it decides to work.

[image: Now it wants to work]

One thing to note, though, I turned off the Maximize and Minimize titlebar buttons.

[image: Removed Maximize and Minimize buttons]

Either way, I'm a happy camper